# File not enqueueing

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I hate to add to the multitude of "script not enqueueing" questions, but I can't seem to figure out why my "tablesorter" scripts won't enqueue. The other script (customsjs) in the same directory is enqueuing nicely, but the tablesorter scripts won't.

```
function load_customs(){

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker');
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');

    wp_register_script( 'customjs', plugins_url( '/js/site-customjs.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'customjs' );

    wp_register_script( 'tablesorterjs', plugins_url( '/js/jquery.tablesorter.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( ' tablesorterjs' );

    wp_register_script( 'tablesorterfunctions', plugins_url( '/js/tablesorter.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( ' tablesorterfunctions' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'tablesorter', plugins_url( '/css/tablesorter/style.css', __FILE__ ) );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_customs');
```

I've verified that the files are in their appropriate location and the console in Chrome isn't throwing any errors.

To clarify - my problem is the TableSorter JS files not enqueueing. The TableSorter CSS file enqueues just fine.

Is anyone seeing what the problem might be? Thanks!

Comment: do have error for the javascript contained in the external file telling me <noscript> was incorrect

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

Comment: I do not have an error. Thank you for the link to the Codex. That is how I built my calls. Are you seeing something that I missed that I should be re-reading?

Comment: tablesorter is CSS

Comment: if you have problem with above css then you need to change version of in by apply /css/tablesorter/style.css?ver=1.0

Comment: TableSorter is not just CSS: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm not having a problem with the CSS. I'm having a problem with the JS. The TableSorter CSS loads fine. The TableSorter JS is not enqueueing.

Comment: can we move into chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35135/discussion-between-yazmin-and-vasim-vanzara).

Comment: wp_register_script( 'tablesorterjs','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.25.3/js/jquery.tablesorter.js'); 
wp_enqueue_script( ' tablesorterjs' );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with my enqueue statements. There was a space ahead of the handle name of the wp_enqueue_scripts statements for both "tablesorterjs" and "tablesorterfunctions". Once I removed the space in front of the handle name, the scripts enqueued.

```
wp_register_script( 'tablesorterjs', plugins_url( '/js/jquery.tablesorter.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
wp_enqueue_script( 'tablesorterjs' );

wp_register_script( 'tablesorterfunctions', plugins_url( '/js/tablesorter.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
wp_enqueue_script( 'tablesorterfunctions' );
```